# Crud Operation Error : Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

> class Crud_Pro_Block_Pro extends Mage_Core_Block_Template { } Fatal
>   error: Class 'Crud_Pro_Block_Pro' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on
>   line 491

Comment: Please update your question with the Crud/Pro/Block/Pro.php file.

Comment: In your xml check whether you have given Exact Block class without typo and case sensitive

Comment: please update the question with full code